# Laravel - Helper file with function calls an accessor

Tags: php, laravel, accessor

I have an helper file with my functions accessible from all parts of the project.

In these functions I have one that call an accessor from a model, but I get error when used.

Here the function:

```
function placeholder_decode($placeholder, $documento)
{
    $variables['#document.protocol_number_view#'] = $documento->protocol_number_view;
    
    $string = json_decode(str_replace(array_keys($variables), array_values($variables), $placeholder));

    return $string[0]->value;

}
```

The accessor is the call to `$documento->protocol_number_view`.

This is the code of the accessor into model code:

```
public function getProtocolNumberViewAttribute()
{
    $format = Configuration::select("value")->where("company_id", $this->attributes['company_id'])->where("name", "prot_format")->get();

    if ($this->attributes['protocol_number'] != 0) {
        $number = placeholder_decode($format, $this);
    } else {
        $number = "";
    }
    return $number;
}
```

This is the error I got:

```
[2021-03-10 20:27:54] local.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined property: App\Document::$protocol_number_view in /var/www/protocol/app/helpers.php:15
```

This is the result of dd($documento) into placeholder_decode() function:

```
App\Document {#939
  #table: "documents"
  #fillable: array:13 [
    0 => "company_id"
    1 => "date"
    2 => "type"
    3 => "subject"
    4 => "senderable_type"
    5 => "senderable_id"
    6 => "protocol_number"
    7 => "protocol_date"
    8 => "is_reserved"
    9 => "cancelled"
    10 => "created_user_id"
    11 => "updated_user_id"
    12 => "deleted_user_id"
  ]
  #dates: array:3 [
    0 => "date"
    1 => "protocol_date"
    2 => "deleted_at"
  ]
  #appends: array:1 [
    0 => "protocol_number_view"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:17 [
    "id" => 4
    "company_id" => 1
    "date" => "2020-11-03 19:51:14"
    "type" => "E"
    "subject" => "Richiesta Trofeo"
    "senderable_type" => "App\Address"
    "senderable_id" => 18
    "protocol_number" => 10
    "protocol_date" => "2021-03-10 18:45:50"
    "is_reserved" => 0
    "cancelled" => 0
    "created_user_id" => 1
    "updated_user_id" => 1
    "deleted_user_id" => null
    "created_at" => "2020-11-03 19:51:14"
    "updated_at" => "2021-03-10 18:45:50"
    "deleted_at" => null
  ]
  #original: array:17 [
    "id" => 4
    "company_id" => 1
    "date" => "2020-11-03 19:51:14"
    "type" => "E"
    "subject" => "Richiesta Trofeo"
    "senderable_type" => "App\Address"
    "senderable_id" => 18
    "protocol_number" => 10
    "protocol_date" => "2021-03-10 18:45:50"
    "is_reserved" => 0
    "cancelled" => 0
    "created_user_id" => 1
    "updated_user_id" => 1
    "deleted_user_id" => null
    "created_at" => "2020-11-03 19:51:14"
    "updated_at" => "2021-03-10 18:45:50"
    "deleted_at" => null
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:2 [
    "company" => App\Company {#954
      #table: "companies"
      #fillable: array:4 [
        0 => "name"
        1 => "created_user_id"
        2 => "updated_user_id"
        3 => "deleted_user_id"
      ]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:8 [
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "Federazione"
        "created_user_id" => null
        "updated_user_id" => null
        "deleted_user_id" => null
        "created_at" => "2020-10-08 18:45:47"
        "updated_at" => "2020-10-08 18:45:47"
        "deleted_at" => null
      ]
      #original: array:8 [
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "Federazione"
        "created_user_id" => null
        "updated_user_id" => null
        "deleted_user_id" => null
        "created_at" => "2020-10-08 18:45:47"
        "updated_at" => "2020-10-08 18:45:47"
        "deleted_at" => null
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: array:1 [
        0 => "deleted_at"
      ]
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [
        0 => "*"
      ]
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
    "tags" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#919
      #items: []
    }
  ]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #forceDeleting: false
  #queuedTags: []
}
```

Comment: What error? Please, provide more details.

Comment: @fonini I updated my question with the error I got

Comment: Could you `dd($this)` inside the helper to see if it is an instance of Document?

Comment: you mean in the accessor function?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the accessor.

Comment: yes, I'm sure it works because I call it from other parts of the code. But If I call it from the helper, I get the error...

Comment: What is result of dd($documento); in placeholder_decode() function?

Comment: @MartinApotheosis added in the original post